# dma_set_mask_and_coherent() with 24-bit DMA mask for PCIe on arm64

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, arm64, dma, pci-e

I am writing a PCIe driver and have trouble with setting the DMA mask.

The host is a zcu102 with a Quadcore ARM-Cortex A53. The PCIe device is a custom Device.

The kernel is v5.15.0-1023-xilinx-zynqmp with the [Xilinx Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS](https://ubuntu.com/download/amd).

According to [DMA API HOWTO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) I need to set the DMA mask using `dma_set_mask_and_coherent()`
My device supports a DMA mask of 24 bits.
Therefore I try the following:

```c
status=dma_set_mask_and_coherent(&pdev->dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(24));
```

This returns -5 => -EIO => I/O error.

I have tried the following:

When I try the same code with `DMA_BIT_MASK(32)` it works. So it seems to be a problem with the 24 bits.

I looked at the kernel config `gunzip -c /proc/config.gz  | grep CONFIG_ZONE_DMA`:

```ini
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA=y
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA32=y
```

Which looks okay to me.

My current problem trace is:

1. [dma_set_mask_and_coherent)_](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/include/linux/dma-mapping.h#L442) calls [dma_set_mask()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/kernel/dma/mapping.c#L735).
2. `dma_set_mask()` checks if [dma_supported()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/kernel/dma/mapping.c#L713)(dev,mask) returns zero
3. For DMA_BIT_MASK(24) it returns 0 leading to failure. For DMA_BIT_MASK(32) it returns 1 leading to success.
4. `dma_supported()` checks for a null pointer in `get_dma_ops(dev)`
5. [get_dma_ops()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/include/linux/dma-map-ops.h#L78) implementation depends on CONFIG_DMA_OPS
6. `gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_DMA_OPS` returns `CONFIG_DMA_OPS=y`
7. Since this is enabled: `get_dma_ops()` checks for dev->dma_ops
8. `pr_info("pdev->dev.dma_ops: %p\n", pdev->dev.dma_ops);` returns 0 so the check fails
9. That means `dma_direct_supported()` is called.

Could you please help me answer the following questions:

- Why does dma_direct_supported fail?

Comment: It must be returning false at the line [`return mask >= phys_to_dma_unencrypted(dev, min_mask);`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.140/source/kernel/dma/direct.c#L534) in `dma_direct_supported()`.

Comment: Side note: _Useless use of gzip_. `zgrep ... /proc...` or `zless /proc/...` would do the same in a single call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ian Abbots Hint I took a look at `dma_direct_supported()` and found

```c
min_mask = min_t(u64, min_mask, DMA_BIT_MASK(zone_dma_bits));
```

`zone_dma_bits` resolves to 32 for arm64 so the mask of 24 bits is too small.